# How to get Prerender to work

Tags: html, prefetch, prerender

I recently try to do Prerender and need some enlightenment on It. I try to prerender some of my pages but it fails to load.

In chrome://net-internals/#prerender it will show me Unsupported Scheme.

What i did in my html header is this:

```
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page1">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page2">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page3">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page4">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page5">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page6">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page7">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page8">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page9">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page10">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page11">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page12">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page13">
<link rel="prerender" href="/abc/page14">
```

In chrome://net-internals/#prerender it will show this. Basically all loaded are false.

```
Link Rel Prerender (same domain)    http://example.org/abc/page1    Unsupported Scheme  2016-03-29 13:23:25.

Link Rel Prerender (same domain)    http://example.org/abc/page2    Unsupported Scheme  2016-03-29 13:23:25.

Link Rel Prerender (same domain)    http://example.org/abc/page3    Unsupported Scheme  2016-03-29 13:23:25.

Link Rel Prerender (same domain)    http://example.org/abc/page4    Unsupported Scheme  2016-03-29 13:23:25.

Link Rel Prerender (same domain)    http://example.org/abc/page5    Unsupported Scheme  2016-03-29 13:23:25.

Link Rel Prerender (same domain)    http://example.org/abc/page6    Unsupported Scheme  2016-03-29 13:23:25.
```

and so on until page 14. The whole list will give unsupported scheme.

I am not sure what is wrong and why. Can anyone please let me know what does Unsupported Scheme means? I google around and there seems to be no documentation explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

Given `cross domain`, `Unsupported Scheme`, and `http://` I'd say you need to use scheme-agnostic `//` in your URLs:

```
<link rel="prerender" href="//abc/page1">
<link rel="prerender" href="//abc/page2">
...
```

Or even use complete URLs:

```
<link rel="prerender" href="http://example.com/abc/page1">
<link rel="prerender" href="http://example.com/abc/page2">
...
```

Comment: Actually is same domain. I tried both method what you said (using // and complete url). it doesnt work. Still show unsupported scheme.

Comment: @user3126531 do you have HTML5 doctype?

Comment: Yes I have this <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @user3126531 I've found a 3 years old bug in chrome https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242959, I'd suggest check prerender in other browsers and file a bug if Chrome fails